# Retrieving all localstorage data in a format that can be useful in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I am doing a uni assignment and the part I am up to requires me to pull the data from multiple localstorage keys and compile them in various ways (add them together basically.) I have got the data stored from the form as an array in the following format

```
testname;testcompany;6192742222;email@email.com;1 John St;;Bellevue;6056; ;5;10;20.00;44;64.00;6.40;70.40;
```

Now i may have multiple of these and I need to take a few of them, mainly the figures towards the end, and add them with a variable number of other values from other strings and I am hitting my head against a wall trying to figure it out.

Also because this is a uni assignment I cannot use `jquery`, `JSON` or any server based software.

EDIT: After doing what was suggested below I am still having issues, also I cannot for th life of me get the code to format properly in the comments section so i figured i would put it here.

```
window.onload = getAllItems();

function getAllItems() {
    var i = 0;
    var lslength = localStorage.length-1;
    for (i = 0; i <= lslength; i++) {
        var itemKey = localStorage.key(i);
        var values = localStorage.getItem(itemKey);
        var values2 = values.split(";"); 

        function extract(values2) {
  var result = {};
  result.name = values2[0];
  // ...
  result.email = values2[3];
  // ...
  return result;
}}}
```

Comment: I understand not using jQuery, but no JSON?  This seems like a perfect use case for it, and it actually has better support than localStorage.

Comment: i agree, i would be insanely easy if i could use JSON, but the powers that be have decided we cant, however if worst comes to worst im going to do it anyway, especially seeing as the assessment is due in 16 hours

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the value stored in the `localStorage` is always like this

```
testname;testcompany;6192742222;email@email.com;1 John St;;Bellevue;6056; ;5;10;20.00;44;64.00;6.40;70.40;
```

then you could do

```
// suppose you retrieved that String from localStorage and have it in 
// a variable called data
var dataArray = data.split(';');
```

then you could write a function that maps a position in the array to a name into an object, so that it would be easier to later manipulate it, for example something like:

```
function extract(arrayData) {
  var result = {};
  result.name = arrayData[0];
  // ...
  result.email = arrayData[3];
  // ...
  return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that alberto, so assuming i have say 5 strings stored in localstorage in the exact same format and would like to retrieve them and put them together (ie. the numbers) so i can format them to add up together, how would i go about that?

Comment: To retrieve an element you do `localStorage.getItem(key)`, it's not clear to me what you mean by "add up together", expecially in the case of emails.

Comment: sorry mate, ill clarify. The main parts i want are the ;5;10;20.00;44;64.00;6.40;70.40;
these are costs and prices for a pretend company, now when the company creates a daily report, they want all the figures added together, one might be for tax, so the same part of each string needs to be added together to create a total for the tax, does that clear it up a bit?

Comment: Yes, once you write `extract` it's easy, you just store the result in a variable, say `result`, and do `result.tax`. Next you just need to do this for each object and sum similar values.

Comment: hey, sorry to bug you, i have tried using your code but it doesnt seem to work, if you wouldnt mind having a quick look below and show me where i stuffed it up,
`window.onload = getAllItems();

function getAllItems() {
    var i = 0;
    var lslength = localStorage.length-1;
    for (i = 0; i <= lslLength; i++) {
        var itemKey = localStorage.key(i);
        var values = localStorage.getItem(itemKey);
  var values2 = values.split(";"); 
  
  function extract(values2) {
  var result = {};
  result.name = values2[0];
  // ...
  result.email = values2[3];
  // ...
  return result;
}}}`

Comment: I have added the code in my question as i couldnt get the damn formatting to work in the comments. Thanks again!!